# Grouping location nodes by post code

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph where there are addresses (i.e. locations), with relationships into them. I would like to group together these nodes, so that different location id's that have the same postcode (a property of the location node) become one node, and for the relationships to also point to that new resulting node.

I would appreciate any help or answers with this! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Would that be better modeled as a hierarchy similar to

(c:City)->[:in]->(s:State)->[:in]->(co:Country).

In your case, creating a new Node to represent the geography (Postal Code) 
Linking the Locations to their Postal Code.

Then you can navigate the model from the PC down to the whatever relationships are coming into each location.

(t:thing related to location)->[:happendIn]->(l:location)->[:in]->(p:PostalCode) Your locations won't "become" a new node, they will be Linked to a new node.